# How to rectify Heteroskedasticity/Failed Levene Test in Linear Mixed Models?

Tags: r, mixed-model, heteroscedasticity, levenes-test

I am newer to mixed models and ran into a confusing spot with one of my models because it violated the assumption of homogeneity of variance. I am running this  in R and using lmer from lme4.

Sample of df structure:

```
Subject   Condition   Latency 
   1          A          #
   1          B          #
   2          A          #
   2          B          #
```

Below is my model:

```
m1 = lmer(Latency ~ Condition + (1|Subject))
```

Levene's Test:

```
leveneTest(Latency ~ Condition, data=df)

Levene's Test for Homogeneity of Variance (center = median)
      Df F value    Pr(>F)    
group  2   13.39 5.525e-05 ***
  33
```

I have read that transforming may be the preferred way to handle this, but I have read different things (such as Welch–Satterthwaite adjustment for F value, generalized linear model) and am really not certain what is the correct solution and how to implement it/what type of transformation. I guess it all boils down to two questions really:

1) What is the appropriate method to handle the violation of this assumption (and would it be different if were Condition*Hour).

2) Any information on how to handle the above in R would be a greatly appreciated (if that doesn't fit beyond the scope of Cross Validated)

Thanks

Edit:

N=11, There are 3 conditions and the aim is to compare the effect each condition has to one another on the latency

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way of handling this is to do any appropriate outlier test and then to remove this from the model. Now, there needs to be an appropriate reason for removing it from the model. Often you will find out that a cell has a typo (forgetting to add the decimal is a common one). That can be a common culprit.

Have you looked at the shape of your residuals? I find that a much more preferable way of diagnosing what needs to be done. If I see that the issue is an influential outlier, I can deal with that. If I see that the issue is increased variance as a variable increases in value, I think what to do.

For example, in my work, I often deal with violations in this regard due to ceiling effects. Think of it like this- Imagine a strength test to measure success in the NFL of people. Further imagine that my strength measure was only a bench press set that had weights up to 100kg total. There would be an incredible ceiling and you would have a violation.

Now you can do two things, you can use a transformation to deal with this...or it might be that your variables are just not good. In the above example, a weight set that goes up to 500kg is a much better measure of strength than on that goes up to 100kg due to the ceiling effect.

Comment: I think it may be a ceiling effect, of the animals (subjects) two of them had latencies that superseded the testing window of 30 sec (standard for the task) w/ another that was close. Thus those two are logged at 30. So would the preferred action be to just remove them as outliers and reevaluate?